# Knockout add new row to list of records mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using mapping plugin for updating view model like so:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (json) {
                if (json.Page == 1) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(json, {}, self);
                } else {
                    self.List().push(ko.mapping.fromJS(json.List));
                }
                console.log(ko.toJSON(self.List()));
            },
        });
```

however instead of updating a List() observable array (adding only NEW items when ajax call completes - for page 2 (next several items from DB), it adds a new List => Notice "[" element in the console output:

**AJAX response (json)**

{"DiscountType":"Transaction","List":[{"ActivationDate":"/Date(1427215761818)/","CustomerName":"Another two 2","CustomerNumber":4328,"Percent":20,"HasDiscount":true},{"ActivationDate":"/Date(1428079761818)/","CustomerName":"Another tree","CustomerNumber":1212,"Percent":20,"HasDiscount":true}],"Page":2}

**Console Output:**

[{"ActivationDate":"/Date(1388556000000)/","CustomerName":"Test1 Inc.","CustomerNumber":10032,"Percent":20,"HasDiscount":true},{"ActivationDate":"/Date(1426783761818)/","CustomerName":"Another One 1","CustomerNumber":5174,"Percent":20,"HasDiscount":true},[{"ActivationDate":"/Date(1427215761818)/","CustomerName":"Another two 2","CustomerNumber":4328,"Percent":20,"HasDiscount":true},{"ActivationDate":"/Date(1428079761818)/","CustomerName":"Another tree","CustomerNumber":1212,"Percent":20,"HasDiscount":true}]]

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the contents of json.List? Your issue seems to be that json.List is an Array, and you're pushing that Array object as an element into your existing Array, rather than the individual elements in the Array.

Comment: that's correct. json List is an array. how would I push just individual elements?. would properties of the new List elements be handled correctly by the mapping plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push the individual elements of your returned array, do something like

```
success: function (json) {
    if (json.Page == 1) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(json, {}, self);
    }
    else {
        json.List.forEach( 
            function(element) {
               self.List.push( ko.mapping.fromJS(element) );
            } );
        }
    console.log(ko.toJSON(self.List()));
        }
```

```js
var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.List = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.initiate = function() {
    json = JSON.parse('{"DiscountType":"Transaction","List":[{"ActivationDate":"/Date(1427215761818)/","CustomerName":"Another two 2","CustomerNumber":4328,"Percent":20,"HasDiscount":true},{"ActivationDate":"/Date(1428079761818)/","CustomerName":"Another tree","CustomerNumber":1212,"Percent":20,"HasDiscount":true}],"Page":2}');
    json.List.forEach(function(entry) {
      self.List.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(entry));
    });
  };
};
vm = new vm();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.initiate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js'></script>
<html>

<div data-bind='foreach: List'>
  <div data-bind='text: ActivationDate'></div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this:[....+"__ko_mapping__":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"ActivationDate":true,"CustomerName":true,"CustomerNumber":true,"Percent":true,"HasDiscount":true},"copiedProperties":{}}},{"ActivationDate":"/Date(1428079761818)/","CustomerName":"Another tree","CustomerNumber":1212,"Percent":20,"HasDiscount":true,"__ko_mapping__":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"ActivationDate":true,"CustomerName":true,"CustomerNumber":true,"Percent":true,"HasDiscount":true},"copiedProperties":{}}}]

Comment: Some weird characters are showing in console.log(self.List());

Comment: I added a code snippet to give you a feel for how to handle this.

Comment: both you and OP are making a critical error: you're evaluating the observableArray before you push: `self.List().push( ko.mapping.fromJS(element) );` should be `self.List.push( ko.mapping.fromJS(element) );`

Comment: @dperry Yeah I just copied his code for the initial answer, but when I wrote it out myself I noticed that and corrected it.